# Returning the results of a select statement that uses a FOR XML PATH('') to condense to one row in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull several values out of some XML that I have and return it as one string from a stored procedure. I have created the select statement that will pull all of the rows into one.

This is the code that I currently have.

```
CREATE FUNCTION openrpt.getSearchTermNames (@searchID NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @xmlData XML 
  DECLARE @Names XML 
  SET @xmlData = 
  ( 
         SELECT QueryXML 
         FROM   ConflictsSearchTerms 
         WHERE  ConflictsSearchTerms.[ID] = @searchID); 
  WITH xmlnamespaces ( default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntApp.Wilco.Model.Conflicts.Searches', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' AS d2p1, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i ) 
  RETURN 
  ( 
         SELECT '; ' + temp.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/ConflictsSearchTermQuery/TermItems/d2p1:string') AS XMLDATA(temp)
         UNION 
         SELECT '; ' + temp.value('d2p1:Value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                                                 AS [Test]
         FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/ConflictsSearchTermQuery/CorporateTreeCompaniesById/d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring') AS XMLDATA(temp) FOR XML PATH('') 
  )
```

The select statemt will correctly return a list of the items from those two fields in the XML seperated by semi-colons but I am getting a syntax error at the return .  I also get an error that says

```
The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.
```

Comment: Did you try with `Returns Nvarchar(MAX) AS` instead of Varchar?

Comment: Yes I tried that I still get the syntax error at RETURN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION openrpt.getSearchTermNames
    (
      @searchID NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @xmlData XML 
        DECLARE @Names XML 
        DECLARE @x XML


        SET @xmlData = ( SELECT QueryXML
                         FROM   ConflictsSearchTerms
                         WHERE  ConflictsSearchTerms.[ID] = @searchID
                       ); 

        WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntApp.Wilco.Model.Conflicts.Searches', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' AS d2p1, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i ) 
        SELECT @x =  
        ( SELECT * FROM (
             SELECT '; ' + temp.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Test]
             FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/ConflictsSearchTermQuery/TermItems/d2p1:string') AS XMLDATA(temp)
             UNION 
             SELECT '; ' + temp.value('d2p1:Value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                                                 
             FROM   @xmlData.nodes('/ConflictsSearchTermQuery/CorporateTreeCompaniesById/d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring') AS XMLDATA(temp))t 
             FOR XML PATH('') 
        )

        RETURN CAST(@x AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    END
```

Comment: This allows me to return the value but it adds XML tags that I do not want.  It adds a node called Test that it places that values in rather than just returning the list of the values

Comment: I solved this by just adding two replace statements to get rid of the tags. Thanks for your help